# Position div within a list item in the middle

Tags: html, css

I have a div in a list item which is floated right. The div positions it self at the top right corner of the list item. Is it possible to position it in the middle-right without the use of padding or margins?

```
---------------
           DIV


---------------
```

Needs to be:

```
---------------

            DIV

---------------
```

Comment: Did you end up resolving your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I made a bunch of assumptions and didn't bother check this first.

```
li {
  height:       32px;
}

li div {
  width:        100%;
  line-height:  32px;
  text-align:   center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the div to take up the full space you could position the div this way:

```
li div {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}
```

or if you don't want it to take up the full space

```
li div {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    top: 50%;
    height:80%;
    margin-top:-40%; // Half of height
}
```

If you have a hard coded list height and div height:

```
li { height: 50px; }
li div {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
    height:30px;
    top: 10px;
}
```

There are many ways to do this, you should provide more information on how you want it to behave and look

Answer (score 0):

You could use the table cell method.

```
<div class="wrap one">
    <div class="inner-wrap">
        <div class="inner">Test</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With the CSS defining a parent as a table, then table-cell with vertical align:

```
.wrap .inner {
    background: white;
    float: right;
}

.wrap.one {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}
.wrap.one .inner-wrap {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/vFqSC/

Comment: Setting up a table within a list item just to position one div seems a little much

Comment: It is, but without adjusting the margin/padding I can only imagine adjusting the line-height or inserting an placeholder div to centre it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can, but margin or padding is the preferred method, but you could use relative positioning and assess a amount along on vertical axis. fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/De4CV/1/

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background:#333;
}
div p {
    font:1em normal Futura, sans-serif;
    color:#f5f5f5;
    text-align:right;
    position:relative;
    top:90px;
}

<div class="div">
    <p>Hello there!</p>
</div>
```